# How can I count the occurrence an entire string(not substring) in a python dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, nlp, data-science

I have a list of words which i need to match as a whole string in a column named "Description"

For example :
Description- **Robert is a great R PROGRAMMER!**

My Code:

```
`m=['Refresh','Update','R','Notebook']
```

The next piece of code is where I need help on:

```
data['Matched_count']=data.description.str.count('|'.join(m))
```

The above gives me a count of the substring match. For example - all the 'R' being used in the description is counted

```
data['Matched_count']=data.description.str.contains('|'.join(m)).astype(int)
```

The above just gives me a flag of 0 and 1 for the substring match

```
data['Matched_count']=data.description.str.match('|'.join(m)).astype(int)
```

This comes close to the entire String matching . However this doesnt give me the count of the string .It just flags it as 1 or 0 based on it being present in the Description

I need to count the occurrence of the entire string in the dataframe in a new column

Comment: does this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/36447145/6660373?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46764842/6660373

Comment: It works with a single key word. But how do i work around with adding a list of words to it?
data['Matched_count']=data.description.str.count(r'(?<!\S)'|'.join(m)(?!\S)') doesnt work.

and neither does : data['Matched_count']=data.description.str.count(r'(?<!\S)Refresh,R,Notebook(?!\S)')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exact string match str.count(), pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764572/exact-string-match-str-count-pandas-python)