# Keyword categorization from strings in a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, python-re

This is not the best approach but this what I did so far:

I have this example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                  'City': ['I lived Los Angeles', 'I visited London and Toronto','the best one is Toronto', 'business hub is in New York',' Mexico city is stunning']
                   })

df
```

gives:

```
    City
0   I lived Los Angeles
1   I visited London and Toronto
2   the best one is Toronto
3   business hub is in New York
4   Mexico city is stunning
```

I am trying to match (case insensitive) city names from a nested dic and create a new column with the country name with int values for statistical  purposes.

So, here is my nested dic as a reference  for countries and cities:

```
country = { 'US': ['New York','Los Angeles','San Diego'],
         'CA': ['Montreal','Toronto','Manitoba'],
         'UK': ['London','Liverpool','Manchester']      
       }
```

and  I created a function that should look for the city from the df and match it with the dic, then create a column with the country name:

```
def get_country(x):
    count = 0
    for k,v in country.items():
        for y in v:
            if y.lower() in x:
                df[k] = count + 1
            else:
                return None
```

then applied it to df:

```
df.City.apply(lambda x: get_country(x.lower()))
```

I got the following output:

```
    City                              US
0   I lived Los Angeles               1
1   I visited London and Toronto      1
2   the best one is Toronto           1
3   business hub is in New York       1
4   Mexico city is stunning           1
```

Expected output:

```
    City                              US    CA   UK
0   I lived Los Angeles               1      0    0
1   I visited London and Toronto      0      1    1
2   the best one is Toronto           0      1    0
3   business hub is in New York       1      0    0
4   Mexico city is stunning           0      0    0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pandas count number of Regex matches in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401422/python-pandas-count-number-of-regex-matches-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on your function. I changed the name of the variables to be more readable and easy to follow.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'City': ['I lived Los Angeles', 
             'I visited London and Toronto',
             'the best one is Toronto', 
             'business hub is in New York',
             ' Mexico city is stunning']
})


country_cities = { 
    'US': ['New York','Los Angeles','San Diego'],
    'CA': ['Montreal','Toronto','Manitoba'],
    'UK': ['London','Liverpool','Manchester']      
}

def get_country(text):
    text = text.lower()
    count = 0
    country_counts = dict.fromkeys(country_cities, 0)
    
    for country, cities in country_cities.items():
        for city in cities:
            if city.lower() in text:
                country_counts[country] += 1 
                
    return pd.Series(country_counts)

df = df.join(df.City.apply(get_country))
```

Output:

```
                           City  US  CA  UK
0           I lived Los Angeles   1   0   0
1  I visited London and Toronto   0   1   1
2       the best one is Toronto   0   1   0
3   business hub is in New York   1   0   0
4       Mexico city is stunning   0   0   0
```

---

**Solution based on `Series.str.count`**

A simpler solution is using [`Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) to count the occurences of the following regex pattern `city1|city2|etc` for each country (the pattern matches `city1` or `city2` or `etc`). Using the same setup as above:

```
country_patterns = {country: '|'.join(cities) for country, cities in country_cities.items()}

for country, pat in country_patterns.items():
    df[country] = df['City'].str.count(pat)
```

---

**Why your solution doesn't work?**

> ```
> if y.lower() in x:
>                df[k] = count + 1
>            else:
>                return None
> ```

The reason your function doesn't produce the right output is that
you are returning `None` if a city is not found in the text: the remaining countries and cities are not checked, because the `return` statement automatically exits the function.

What is happening is that only `US` cities are checked, and the line `df[k] = 1` (in this case `k = 'US'`) creates an entire column named `k` filled with the value 1. It's not creating a single value for that row, it creates or modifies the full column. When using `apply` you want to change a single row or value (the input of function), so don't change directly the main DataFrame inside the function.

Comment: @Mtaly I added the explanation of why your solution fails. See if it helps

Comment: @Mtaly I added a simpler solution if you prefer ;)

Comment: Thanks @Rodalm, the shorter solution also provides the incremental count of cities (search terms), so if the string has `I love London and visited London last year` .. your second solution will count London **twice** which is an additional function that help me in my statistical proposal :)

Comment: @Mtaly You are welcome, I'm glad to help! The first should count multiple occurrences as well :p But I would also use the second, it is simpler and should be faster! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this result using a lambda function to check if any city for each country is contained in the string, after first lower-casing the city names in `country`:

```
cl = { k : list(map(str.lower, v)) for k, v in country.items() }
for ctry, cities in cl.items():
    df[ctry] = df['City'].apply(lambda s:any(c in s.lower() for c in cities)).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
                           City  US  CA  UK
0           I lived Los Angeles   1   0   0
1  I visited London and Toronto   0   1   1
2       the best one is Toronto   0   1   0
3   business hub is in New York   1   0   0
4       Mexico city is stunning   0   0   0
```